# Trigger select field on a click of a different button sencha touch

Tags: cordova, extjs, sencha-touch, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new in sencha.
I try to trigger selectfield on a click of a different button in Sencha based design requirement,

```
                    {

                    "xtype": "container",
                    //"shrinkWrap": false,
                    //"width": "100%",
                    //"height": "100%",
                    style: {
                        //"padding-bottom": "5px",
                    },

                    "layout": {
                        "type": "hbox",
                        "align": "stretch"
                    },
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "xtype": "container",
                            "flex": 1,
                            "layout": {
                                "type": "hbox",
                                "align": "stretch"
                            },
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'textfield',
                                    placeHolder: 'Subject',
                                    id: 'rejectSubject',
                                    name: 'rejectSubject',
                                    itemId: 'rejectSubject',
                                    hidden: true,
                                    //readOnly: true,
                                    //width: "100%",
                                    //columnWidth: 0.5
                                    flex: 1,
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'button',
                                    flex: 0.1,
                                    style: {
                                        'position': 'absolute',
                                        'right': '5px',
                                        'height': '35px',
                                        'border': '0px none',
                                        'background': ' #fff',
                                    },

                                    html: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                                    autoEl: {
                                        tag: 'right'
                                    },
                                    handler: function () {
                                        Ext.get('templateemail').dom.click();
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'selectfield',
                                    //cls: 'field-border-right',
                                    //label: 'Email ',
                                    name: 'template_id',
                                    itemId: 'template_id',
                                    id: 'templateemail',
                                    hidden: true,
                                    listeners: {
                                        change: function () {
                                            if (this.getValue() > 0) {
                                                //                                                    this.parent.down('label[name=templateError]').setHidden(true);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                             ]
                        }

                    ]
                },
```

Look like:

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use `showPicker()` on the selectfield

> **showPicker( )**
>
> Shows the picker for the select field, whether that is a Ext.picker.Picker or a simple list.

```
Ext.getCmp('templateemail').showPicker();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I face another problem that when I click button app select popup auto select last option every time, because of that I am not able to generate the validation message. Please help.

Comment: I think you need to give `autoSelect:false` in selectfield